# Penrose diagram of Schwarzschild-AdS space

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I want to construct the conformal Penrose diagram for the Schwarzschild Anti-deSitter spacetime (SAdS). However, I am having trouble eliminating the coordinate singularity at the event horizon. My approach (and the step where I am having problems) are outlined below:

---

$(\textbf{Step 1}) \enspace$ Consider a black hole in asymptotically Anti-deSitter spacetime. It has metric

$$g \enspace = \enspace -f(r) \, dt^2 + \frac{1}{f(r)} \, dr^2 + r^2 \, d \Omega^2 \quad , $$

where

$$ f(r) \enspace = \enspace 1 - \frac{2m}{r} + \frac{r^2}{a^2} \quad ,$$

or by eliminating $m$:

$$ f(r) = \enspace 1 - \frac{r_+}{r} \Big( 1 + \frac{r_+^2}{a^2} \Big) + \frac{r^2}{a^2} \quad .$$

with $r_+$ being the event horizon.

$(\textbf{Step 2}) \enspace$ I define the tortoise coordinate

$$ dr_{\ast} \enspace = \enspace \frac{1}{f(r)} \, dr \quad , $$

which Wolfram Alpha calculates to be

$$ r_{\ast}(r) \enspace = \enspace C_0 + C_1 \,  \ln \bigg[ \frac{ (r - r_+)^2}{( r_+^2 + r_+ r + r^2 + a^2)} \bigg] + C_2 \, \arctan( C_3 \, r + C_4 ) $$

where $C_0, C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4$ are some constants depending on $r_+$ and $a^2$.

$(\textbf{Step 3}) \enspace$ I rewrite the metric with coordinates $u = t - r_{\ast}$ and $v = t + r_{\ast}$:

$$ g \enspace = \enspace - f(r) \; du \, dv + r^2 \, d\Omega^2 $$

$(\textbf{Step 4}) \enspace$ I again rewrite the metric with coordinates $U = - \exp ( - \lambda u )$ and $V = \exp ( \lambda v )$:

$$ g \enspace = \enspace - \frac{f(r)}{\lambda^2} \exp ( -2\lambda r_{\ast} ) \; dU \, dV + r^2 \, d\Omega^2 $$.

$(\textbf{Step 5}) \enspace$ Now I am stuck. I should be able to choose $\lambda$ such that the coordinate singularity at $r = r_+$ vanishes, but by choosing $-2\lambda = \pm \tfrac{1}{C_1}$, I find that I do not get rid of that singularity, because

$$ f(r) \cdot \Big( \frac{(r-r_+)^2}{r_+^2 + r_+ r + r^2 + a^2} \Big)^{\pm 1} \enspace = \enspace \begin{cases} \frac{ (r - r_+)^3}{a^2 r} & \text{exponent = +1} \\
\frac{ (r_+^2 + r_+ r^2 + a^2)^2}{a^2r(r-r_+)} & \text{exponent = -1} \end{cases}$$

so the metric either blows up or becomes singular at the event horizon. What is the trick here; what am I overseeing; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried expanding $r_{*}$ *before* choosing $\lambda$?

Comment: Or differently put why are you choosing $-2\lambda =\pm C_1$?

Comment: I want to exploit the identity $\exp( \ln ( x ) ) = x$ in order to get some term proportional to $1/f(r)$ or something similar which takes care of the coordinate singularity. This means I want $-2\lambda \cdot C_1 = 1$, so that the $\ln$ has unit prefactor. **EDIT:** there was a mistake in the question, I chose $-2 \lambda = \pm 1/C_1$. I corrected the mistake. Sorry for that.

Comment: Hint: $\exp(\alpha\log(x)) = x^\alpha$